# Only Wrap Text to new Line if Max-Width is reached?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple div like this:

```
<div id="containerDIV">
    <div>THIS IS SOME TEXT</div>
</div>
...
#containerDIV {
    max-width:200px;
}
```

However when running the code, the text shows up like this on the page:

```
THIS IS
SOME TEXT
```

Why is this happening? Eventhough the text has not reached the max width, it appears to wrap to a new line. How can I force the text to be in a single line until it reaches the max-width, and then move to the next line?

Here is a fiddle outlining the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/v2p2xvjh/1/

I tried to set the min-width as suggested, but this will look strange when a short text is displayed in the field. As the container div is now too wide for the short text.

Comment: Hi - were you figure out a way to achieve this where the text wraps only after it reaches max-width.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE #1**

Because you are using "position:absolute".  This will force your div's width to 0px, if no width is defined.  The max-width:200px will allow anything between 0px to 200px.  If you use min-width:200px you will allow from 200px to infinite px.

Here is jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v2p2xvjh/2/

**OLD**

The issue appears to be with the font-size or font-family that you are using.  It may also be affected if the parent element's width is smaller than 200px.

Testing this on jsFiddle it works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/0wg3hodx/1/

```
<div id="containerDIV">
    <div>THIS IS SOME TEXT</div>
</div>

#containerDIV {
    max-width:200px;
}
```

This is because there is enough space for it to reach max-width: 200px.

You will need to look at the CSS (width/padding/margin/font) of the surrounding elements to fix the issue.

Comment: Did you have a look at my fiddle? I am using the same font as you in that example.

Comment: @SidneydeVries it is showing on a single line on my screen.

Comment: I made a mistake when updating my fiddle. Can you check now?

Comment: @SidneydeVries it is the max-width: 200px.  If you want to force a minimum width, use min-width:200px.  "max-width" will allow anything from 0px to 200px.

Comment: Yeah but then if the text is short, the div will be too wide.